# How to escape hyphens when performing yq replace in file command

Tags: input, text, replace, yq

Currently, I am trying to replace the contents of a variable within a yaml file using yq. When doing so I receive an invalid input text error and since first coming across this error i've noticed that it doesn't appreciate the hyphens in the variable and so it kills the command. Below an example of what i see

```
[ec2-user@ip-146-69-172-7 example]$ yq -e -i ".variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = $(yq -r -oy .id rancher_api_project_creation_response.json)" example-variables.yml -vvv
19:33:39 processArgs [DEBU] processed args: [.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = c-tt27c:p-4bp9x example-variables.yml]
19:33:39 maybeFile [DEBU] checking '.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = c-tt27c:p-4bp9x' is a file
19:33:39 maybeFile [DEBU] error: stat .variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = c-tt27c:p-4bp9x: no such file or directory
19:33:39 maybeFile [DEBU] result: false
19:33:39 processArgs [DEBU] assuming expression is '.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = c-tt27c:p-4bp9x'
19:33:39 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] checking file extension 'example-variables.yml' for auto format detection
19:33:39 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] detected format 'yml'
19:33:39 initCommand [DEBU] Using input format yml
19:33:39 initCommand [DEBU] Using output format yml
19:33:39 CreateTempFile [DEBU] WriteInPlaceHandler: writing to tempfile: /tmp/temp1936411158
19:33:39 ParseExpression [DEBU] Parsing expression: [.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = c-tt27c:p-4bp9x]
19:33:39 func1 [DEBU] PathToken variables
19:33:39 func1 [DEBU] PathToken RANCHER_PROJECT_ID
19:33:39 func1 [DEBU] assignOpToken =
Error: 1:33: invalid input text "c-tt27c:p-4bp9x"
```

Here is an example of me testing some basic text to figure out it was the hyphens causing the issue

```
[ec2-user@ip-146-69-172-7 example]$ yq -e -i ".variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = $(echo "12-34:56-78")" example-variables.yml -vvv
20:03:31 processArgs [DEBU] processed args: [.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = 12-34:56-78 example-variables.yml]
20:03:31 maybeFile [DEBU] checking '.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = 12-34:56-78' is a file
20:03:31 maybeFile [DEBU] error: stat .variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = 12-34:56-78: no such file or directory
20:03:31 maybeFile [DEBU] result: false
20:03:31 processArgs [DEBU] assuming expression is '.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = 12-34:56-78'
20:03:31 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] checking file extension 'example-variables.yml' for auto format detection
20:03:31 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] detected format 'yml'
20:03:31 initCommand [DEBU] Using input format yml
20:03:31 initCommand [DEBU] Using output format yml
20:03:31 CreateTempFile [DEBU] WriteInPlaceHandler: writing to tempfile: /tmp/temp3358661156
20:03:31 ParseExpression [DEBU] Parsing expression: [.variables.RANCHER_PROJECT_ID = 12-34:56-78]
20:03:31 func1 [DEBU] PathToken variables
20:03:31 func1 [DEBU] PathToken RANCHER_PROJECT_ID
20:03:31 func1 [DEBU] assignOpToken =
20:03:31 createValueOperation [DEBU] creating value op for string 12
20:03:31 createValueOperation [DEBU] creating value op for string -34
20:03:31 createValueOperation [DEBU] creating value op for string 56
20:03:31 createValueOperation [DEBU] creating value op for string -78
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing variables (55)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding pipe because the next thing is traverse
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing RANCHER_PROJECT_ID (55)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing ASSIGN (40)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing 12 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing -34 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing CREATE_MAP (15)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] tokenIsOpType: createMapOpType
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] tokenIsOpType: createMapOpType
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing 56 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU] processing -78 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 handleToken [DEBU]   adding token to the fixed list
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken variables (55)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put variables (55) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken SHORT_PIPE (45)
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped variables (55) from opstack to results
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put SHORT_PIPE (45) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken RANCHER_PROJECT_ID (55)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put RANCHER_PROJECT_ID (55) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken ASSIGN (40)
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped RANCHER_PROJECT_ID (55) from opstack to results
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped SHORT_PIPE (45) from opstack to results
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put ASSIGN (40) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken 12 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put 12 (int64) (50) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken -34 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put -34 (int64) (50) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken CREATE_MAP (15)
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped -34 (int64) (50) from opstack to results
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped 12 (int64) (50) from opstack to results
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped ASSIGN (40) from opstack to results
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put CREATE_MAP (15) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken 56 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put 56 (int64) (50) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken -78 (int64) (50)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] put -78 (int64) (50) onto the opstack
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken )
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped -78 (int64) (50) from opstack to results
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped 56 (int64) (50) from opstack to results
20:03:31 popOpToResult [DEBU] popped CREATE_MAP (15) from opstack to results
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] opstackLen: 0
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] PostFix Result:
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > variables
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > RANCHER_PROJECT_ID
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > SHORT_PIPE
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > -34 (int64)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > 12 (int64)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > ASSIGN
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > -78 (int64)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > 56 (int64)
20:03:31 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] > CREATE_MAP
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree variables
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree RANCHER_PROJECT_ID
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree SHORT_PIPE
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree -34 (int64)
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree 12 (int64)
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree ASSIGN
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree -78 (int64)
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree 56 (int64)
20:03:31 createExpressionTree [DEBU] pathTree CREATE_MAP
Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

I just need to figure out how to force the expression to recognize the hyphens as an actual piece of the new variable value and escape them somehow.

Comment: Please provide a representative subset of your input files, as well as [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq you are using.